# Command line (or equivalent) tools for .NET development

Tags: .net, visual-studio, command-line, powershell, cmd

Spending most of my time in Visual Studio and using all the IDE tools, I wish I could spend more time using either of the following.

- The Command Window in Visual Studio
- CMD.EXE
- [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin), [MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW)...
- PowerShell.
- Scripts?

What are your favorite and essential commands to type in, opposed to keyboard shortcuts or clicking around?

Comment: Please mark as community wiki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my larger projects, I started to create customized [build.cmd](http://devio.wordpress.com/2008/08/18/building-visual-studio-solutions-from-batch-file/) batch files which themselves call command line tools like:

- [graspx](http://www.devio.at/index.php/graspx) to check .aspx files,
- **osql** to generate C# code from an SQL Server database schema and backup the development database,
- **scptxfr** to script the schema,
- **msbuild** to build applications,
- **devenv** to build setup solutions,
- **7za** (7-Zip) to zip stuff.

An occasional [IISReset](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windowsserver2003/library/iis/003ed2fe-6339-4919-b577-6aa965994a9b.mspx) also helps ;)

Comment: mono alternatives:  xbuild, mdrun, mcs.  Install mono here (http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page). and Mono develop here (http://monodevelop.com/)

Answer (score 4):

The most critical PowerShell commands are Get-Command (alias gcm) and Get-Member (alias gm).  Those two commands allow you to explore and exploit most of the functionality available.  Get-Member is great for interactively exploring and working with .NET objects.

The other useful series of commands are:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($relativepath)
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($absolutepath)
```

which allow you to load other assemblies into PowerShell to work with them.

Comment: And via NuGet's PowerShell console you can drive the VS IDE from the command line: http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2012/03/30/using-nuget-powershell-to-replace-missing-macros-in-dev-11.aspx

Answer (score 3):

[NAnt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAnt) and [booi](http://boo.codehaus.org/Interactive+Interpreter) are the biggest ones for me. NAnt provides building, and booi provides a simple way of running .NET code.

Comment: could you provide a link to more info about booi (it apparently is not a google friendly name)

Comment: The Boo interactive interpreter: http://boo.codehaus.org/Interactive+Interpreter

I use IronPython for much the same thing

Answer (score 1):

When creating very small single file command line utilities, I like to code in something less cumbersome than Visual Studio, like [Notepad2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad2). Then I use **mcs**, the command line compiler bundled with the .NET Framework to compile the source into an assembly.

I think it can be fun and good for my memory to sometimes see how much of the framework I actually remember how to use without actively using [IntelliSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense) all the time. Sorry, got a bit off topic there. :)

Answer (score 1):

For standard development I use csc.exe and msbuild.exe. Other useful tools are wsdl.exe and svcutil.exe for web service development, and in rare cases [ildasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/496e4ekx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and tlbimp.exe.

Oh, yes, and then I absolutely love [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell), but that's a whole book on it's own :-)

Answer (score 0):

I create helper batch files and run them from the command line.

I also use `msbuild` to build Visual Studio solutions, and `nunit-console` to run NUnit unit tests (I have a batch file for that). Plus all the regular cmdline goodness like `grep`, `vim`, and `svn`.

Answer (score 0):

An excellent pattern I once saw was to have a pre-compile command to retrieve the [WSDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) from a web service and generate the appropriate wrapper class using the wsdl.exe tool. I took that same pattern in a recent project and had the `xsd.exe` tool generate classes from my XML schema files.

While you won't be typing in the commands interactively, you certainly need to develop something that works as well and be familiar with the host (.bat scripting, [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell), whatever). Visual Studio exposes some interesting environment-like variables to help locate your project source, etc. Good stuff.